# How inference an inception pb model by restful API with tensorflow serving?

Tags: tensorflow, model, serving

I have got an incepiton pb Model by github:"serving/tensorflow_serving/example/inception_saved_model.py".I want to got predict by restful API ,but found  an error message.I want to know the argument "images" that how to do or what is correctly format data ?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dU3Pc.png)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to encode the string so that it is websafe. Web-safe means that the encoder uses - and _ instead of + and /.

See [the documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/io/encode_base64) for more info.